# Are there any improvements in the Mavericks Terminal app?

Tags: terminal, macos

Most OS X updates have included a few tweaks to the Terminal app. I know that Mavericks has upgraded a lot of command-line tools, but I haven't seen any reports of changes in Terminal.app itself. Has anyone noticed any?

Comment: I’m sure I’ve read about some enhancements to Terminal in one of the Mavericks reviews that I read, but I can’t find which it was/what they were. /o\

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate? The linked question has nothing to do with terminal.app

Comment: The linked question is trying to collect all features/improvements specific to Mavericks. I agree that it does not specifically focus on Terminal alone, but let's try to keep all the Mavericks specific details in one thread.

Answer (score -1):

I believe Mavericks added pwd restoration (after quitting and relaunching)

Comment: That was already supported in Lion.